# Windows batch file cannot find the subfiles files from the used python file

Tags: python, batch-file

I wrote a batch file to start multiple `.py` files which creates a geodatabase + feature classes (with domains).  The `.py` uses a second/sub `.py` file and a `.csv` file to gain his input.

I get a failure because the `.bat` cannot find this `.csv`. What am I missing?

Current code of the `.bat`:

```
@echo on
"c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\scripts\propy.bat" "C:\Users\<restofthepath>\mainfile.py"
Pause
```

The file & map structure are the following:

[image: The file & map structure are the following:]

I added "call" to the *.bat file and although the pause in the script is working now properly, I still get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   

    File "C:\Users\<restofthepath>\mainfile.py", line 52, in <module> with open(<theCSVfile>) as infile: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: <nameofthecsvfile>.csv'
```

line 52 in the mainscript contains the following line:

```
with open(<theCSVfile>) as infile:
    mw_fields  = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter = ';')
```

Do I need to add this 'csv.Dictreader' also to my .bat file? (maybe I misunderstood the function of the .batfile)

I do have a mainfile (and subfiles) in each folder.

Comment: You have a batch file (*shown*), that calls another batch file (`propy`), that starts a python file (`mainfile`)?   That seems like an lot of layering.

Comment: you have a batch file calling another batch, please show the others content as well?

Comment: Do you have a single `mainfile.py`, or a `mainfile.py` per directory (`map1` and `map2`)? the latter is what your image suggests, please clarify as per my request above as well as this comment.

Comment: You did not read or attempt to answer any of the questions I asked you.

Comment: I am sorry, I was focussing on the another thread.  For All the questions above: "@GerhardBarnard": I have a mainfile.py per directory. (and will add this information to my main question). For the another content (in this case the mainfile and the csv)  I need to ask permission for this. I was allowed to use it, but I think it is not polite to share it without permission.

Comment: @abelenky, I agree on this.  It is a lot of layering, this is made for starters like me, so that you can always edit a file without changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass control to the second batch file, `propy`, control will not come back to the original batch file because you did not use the `call` keyword.

Try instead:

```
@echo on
call "c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\scripts\propy.bat" "C:\Users\<restofthepath>\mainfile.py"
Pause
```

The `call` means "come back to resume executing this file, when the other file is done."

Comment: Thank you for your response gentleman.  I tried it and I got the following error; Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\<restofthepath>\mainfile.py", line 52, in <module> with open(<theCSVfile>) as infile: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: <nameofthecsvfile>.csv. The rest of the information I added to the question above.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, *not* using `call` also does not create a new window, the only difference is that you never return to the calling one; for everything else using `call` or not using it makes not really a difference: same window, same environment, maintained stack levels (`setlocal`/`endlocal`, `pushd`/`popd`, other `call`s)...

Comment: @aschipfl yes. I am aware, I actually misread the statement made by abelenky.. and must admit, I posted my comment half heartedly as well without adding all th details.